# When I search in vim and then press “esc” cursor returns to previous position

Tags: vim

Something has seemingly happened to my vim install, and I'm not exactly sure what. I'm a long time vim user (although I don't use it as a main editor).

When I search:

```
/foo
```

I want to edit the location that it found, so I press ESC (in preparation for getting into insert mode). vim now jumps BACK to where I started from in the file. E.g. if I was on line 0 of a 3000 line file, I search for a particular string, find it at line 1700, and want to edit it - ESC takes me back to line 0.

What's going on? Did I accidentally set some strange mode? Or did I forget a hotkey combination that I should know?

Comment: <esc> cancels search. Just press <cr> instead.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Yeah it probably belongs at https://vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour with the [`incsearch`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'incsearch') option on:

```
Note that the match will be shown, but the cursor will return to its
original position when no match is found and when pressing <Esc>.  You
still need to finish the search command with <Enter> to move the
cursor to the match.
```

If `incsearch` is not on then the cursor doesn't jump to the first match at all, it doesn't move until you press `<Enter>`.

Comment: I don't like this incsearch, so in vim, 
:set nois   will turn it off.
you can also add set nois to the .vimrc to make it as default

Answer (score 3):

you said

> so I press ESC (in preparation for getting into insert mode).

you don't need to press ESC before you can get to insert mode, you need to press <kbd>enter</kbd> (known in vim as `<CR>` for carriage return).

so if you wanted to find `foo` and start inserting text, type

```
/foo<CR>i
```

remember that `<CR>` is a single pressing of the <kbd>enter</kbd> button.